# How to warn about discarding changes with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

**Background:** I am using AngularJS.  I plan to have a user dialog warning before closing the browser window if any changes were made, i.e., "You have unsaved changes.  Changes will be lost.  Continue?"

**Question:** In AngularJS, how would I monitor for ANY change to ANY model? i.e., so that I could set a flag like `var pageWasModified = true;`

In other words, I want to know if ANY model in the entire Angular system has been touched.  Surely I shouldn't have to register a watch for each of my models...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a lot of cases you can just use **myForm.$dirty** property (where myForm is the name of the form), which tells you if the user interacted with the form. Its not exactly what you were asking for, but it might be enough to solve your problem.

If that is not enough, you might want to consider checking out some data management library, like breezejs, which makes checking for model changes very easy. With just angular I dont know of a simple way to check the entire model, you probably would need quite a bit of your own code.

Comment: I accepted this answer because of the reference to breezejs -- thanks for being a problem-solver!

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS sets the CSS classes ng-pristine and ng-dirty on any input field you've used ng-model on, and your FormController has the properties $pristine and $dirty which you can check to see if the form is dirty or not. So yes, it's possible.

So to moniter your all fields no need to use watch, you simply use $scope.myform.$setPristine(); which means your form is not touched or modified yet.
Then if any modification happens then you can check them by using ng-dirty which sets to true if modified else this will be false. So you can either use ngdirty or ngprestine to check.

Second you provide your option in alert box saying do want to save changes once he clicks on save then you set your form to pristine again so that you can keep track for next time change.

Third thing is you have to fire your event on save button so use ngclick. Because if user enters single character then form class changes and ngdirty becomes true.
You can google you will fond lots of example. Sorry i couldnt demostrate now as i am using my cell. 
Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  After some more research it seems that FormController is good for tracking inputs/models on forms... but not necessarily for models elsewhere.  Am I mistaken?